# Serialize 'this'

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

OK, if I have a class like this ...

```
[serializable]
public class MyClass() : ISerializable
{
  public Dictionary<string, object> Values {get; set;}
}
```

I know what I have to do to serialize it (the answer, for those trying to find a quick answer, is this)...

```
protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  Values = (Dictionary<string, object>)info.GetValue("values", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  info.AddValue("values", Values);
}
```

My question is what do I do if, instead, I wanted to defined a class that inherited from Dictionary?

I get this far...

```
[serializable]
public class MyClass() : Dictionary<string, object>, ISerializable
{
  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("me", this);
  }
}
```

but then I get lost. I can't write this ...

```
protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  this = (MyClass)info.GetValue("me", typeof(MyClass));
}
```

'cos 'this' is r/o. So, how would I proceed? Am I even right about the implementation of GetObjectData()?

I don't believe it will make a difference, but just in case it does, I'm writing this under .Net 4.0

Comment: why are you implementing `ISerializable` at all? Default serialization works for almost everything and %90 of the ISerializable implementations I've ever seen are from people who haven't realized that yet.

Comment: @Yaur a: it is **required** when inheriting from something like a dictionary (although I would argue encapsulation is a better idea); that said, b: personally I try not to overly recommend BinaryFormatter - it has... Kinks.

Comment: @Yaur. If I don't, I get an exception as soon as I try deserializing the class instance. I /have/ to implement ISerializable if I'm using a Dictionary in my class.

Comment: I didn't realize that Dictionary implemented `ISerializable` because I generally don't derive from container classes and Dictionary shouldn't actually need to implement it.  You should only need to implement it if you are deriving from it... if you are just using it you should be fine without implementing ISerializable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dictionary<T, V>` already implements `ISerializable` (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy8be3bb.aspx)). So just call the methods in your base class:

```
public class MyClass() : Dictionary<string, object>
{
      protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
          : base(info, context) // Call the constructor in Dictionary
      {
         // instantiate other properties you had added to MyClass.
      }

      public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
      {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context); 
        // Now add other fields that MyClass implements.
        info.AddValue("whatever", this.AnotherProperty); 
      }
}
```

Comment: no kidding?! Bu99er! I guess I just didn't read enough! In my own defense, I only understood about 25% of what I read on this topic anyway! Thanks guy.